# How to bind data Horizontal Dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am developing windows phone 8 app,i want to display image on grid view in Horizontal.But it not get as i want.

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="DataSource"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" SelectionChanged="DataSource_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="gridNews">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding icon}" Stretch="Fill" Height="70" Width="70"></Image>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

this result :

```
image 1
image 2
image 3
image 4
....
```

but i want to display as below :

```
image 1 image 2 image 3

image 4.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a grid you would probably have to put each image in a new "cell" or section of the grid. To do so you would add grid column and then put the images in their respective grids by using grid.column="#"

example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image grid.column="0" />
    <Image grid.column="1" />
    <Image grid.column="2" />
</Grid>
```

I would probably recomend using a stack panel instead though. You can make the orientation horizontal and then all elements in the stack panel will show up in a horizontal orientation.

example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"     Width="100">
     <Image />
     <Image />
     <Image />
</StackPanel>
```

On second thought a Wrap panel may be better for your phone application as it will display the images horizontally and then start a new line once the first line is full. It works almost exactly like the Stack Panel.

example:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"     Width="100">
     <Image />
     <Image />
     <Image />
</WrapPanel>
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may use WrapPanel in [WPToolKit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to make your data show in horizontal.

.Xaml:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

<ListBox 
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       //Binding data here
                       <Image Source={Binding img} />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

in my app,I use wrapPanel in listbox, I'm not sure is it work in longListSelector.

here is a great example about wrapPanel: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-wrappanel-in-depth

hope it helps.